# Unable to supress Bash output when calling script

Tags: bash, shell, background-process

In my main script I have this line to send the output to a log file

`exec >> $LOG_LOCATION/cronout.txt 2>&1`

Which appears to be working fine, however during one step I am calling a background script which runs nethogs. That script should output to a file so I can show  it in a conky panel

```
   echo "$a"
   #background external script
   /home/pi/Documents/ytu/bwidth.sh "$fzm"  "$xy" >/dev/null 2>&1 &
#more stuff......
```

The parameters are the filesize and filename for the nethogs process to awk the rough remaining data

In the external script which runs nethogs I have the line:
`exec > /media/pi/VDRIVE/logs/upl.txt`
Assuming this will then output that to the file I am tailing

But in the output from the initial script (cronout.txt), I am getting the output from nethogs message:

`Waiting for first packet to arrive (see sourceforge.net bug 1019381)`
(This doesnt' present an issue when not run from the initial script, and I am already at the latest version)

The external background script does not appear to execute. I'm going round in circles
and I cant seem to  stop  the error message from breaking the initial script

Comment: You should show a [mcve].

Answer (score 0):

Ok after some additional research this was what worked for me:

`(bwidth.sh  &) &> /dev/null`